# Delphi TIdURI get Path

Tags: delphi

```
uri : TIdURI;
uri:= TIdURI.Create('192.168.1.71:3312/cb.jp2');
```

I want to get **cb.jp2** part of the URI.

`GetPathAndParams` or `Path` methods give the `192.168.1.71:3312` and `192.168.1.71:3312/cb.jp2` so are there any function in TIdURI to get `cb.jp2` ?

Comment: Get it from `uri.Document`.

Comment: @TLama: that should have been posted as an answer rather than a comment.